# .css giving me wrong info about my sections

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a weird issue with .css it gives me the 'block' for every section even though some are 'none'

[image: The code]

keep in min that this is a school exercise and in no way a functional project...

The html file.

```
<body>
<section id="log">
    <form>
        Login <input id="login" type="text"/><br>
        Password <input id="pass" type="password"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button id="authButton">Authentification</button> 
    <button id="inscrButton">Inscription</button><br>
    <br>
</section>

<section id="room">
    <form>
        Room <input id="roomName" type="text"/>
    <button id="creaRoomButton">Créer</button>
    </form>
    <div id="allRooms"></div>
</section>

<section id="chat">
    <textarea id="zone1" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <textarea id="zone2" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button id="envoyButton">Envoyer</button><br>
    <button id="roomButton">retour</button>
    <button id="decoButton">Deconnexion</button>
</section>  

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

This part of  my .js is supposed to display the 'block' section if we do an f5 and verifie if we are still connected, to do so i try to get the section that is display:block so that i can keep it 'block'.

```
var section = "log";    
$('section').each(function(index){
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ": " +  $(this).css('display'));
    if($(this).css('display') === 'block'){
        section = $(this).attr('id');
    }
});

console.log(section)

$.ajax({
    url:"/AuthServlet",
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'estConnecte',
        section: section
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        if(response==='log'){
            $("#log").css('display', "block");
            $("#room").css('display', "none");
            $("#chat").css('display', "none");
        }
        else if(response==='room'){
            $("#log").css('display', "none");
            $("#room").css('display', "block");
            $("#chat").css('display', "none");
        }   
        else{
            $("#log").css('display', "none");
            $("#room").css('display', "none");
            $("#chat").css('display', "block");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of images, can you post your code, so that we have a scope to help you.

Comment: are you showing first element via code?

Comment: Did you try *just* your code?   https://jsfiddle.net/jk6ut0oL/   works fine  (in Chrome at least)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: ok, I'm new here, i'll post some code

Comment: You'll need to post the code that reproduces the issue.  While yes it's an image and should be code, the code within the image does not reproduce the error. So simply adding a code block and removing the image would not be a huge improvement.

Comment: It looks like the debugging console messages are printed first, then the ajax call goes out and alters the `display` css of the elements. Try moving the console messages inside the function, and call that function at the end of the `success` handler of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Chances are its the AJAX that is causing the issue and since you are using that to set the display state of none for some elements - if that isn't working none of the elements will be set t odisplay:none;

This issue might be that you need to trim() the response to remove a whitespace at teh end of the returned message. Try the following :

```
   success: function(response){
      console.log(response)
      var resp = response.trim();
        if(resp==='log'){
            $("#log").css('display', "block");
            $("#room").css('display', "none");
            $("#chat").css('display', "none");
        }
        else if(resp==='room'){
            $("#log").css('display', "none");
            $("#room").css('display', "block");
            $("#chat").css('display', "none");
        }   
        else{
            $("#log").css('display', "none");
            $("#room").css('display', "none");
            $("#chat").css('display', "block");
        }
```